# Connecting to WiFi at boot on an Orange Pi Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux

I'm using an Orange Pi Zero as a base for a WiFi radio. The basic operation should be

1. Boot
2. Connect to Wifi
3. Load bash script using MPD/MPC to connect to wifi stream
4. Set volume
5. Check potentiometer circuit and adjust volume if needed

So far I have the OPi imaged with armbian (jessie) and have the stream connecting, potentiometer working and audio playing. My issue is getting the board to connect to wifi at boot.

The WiFi will connect when I set it up over SSH using either nmtui or armbian-config however when rebooting the OPi will not re-connect.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces #Add at end of file

 auto wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 wpa-ssid <Your Access Point Name aka SSID>
 wpa-psk <Your WPA Password>
```

Wifi connects on boot now,

Credit: https://lucsmall.com/2017/01/19/beginners-guide-to-the-orange-pi-zero/